# Cheese Cutting Tools

Tags: equipment, cheese

I have a large gouda cheese wheel that I need to cut first in half, then quarters etc.  I have seen cheese wheels broken down using a scoring tool and what appears to be a handled wedge tool.  That wedge tool is used instead of cutting.  Does anyone know where I can get these tools or an easier method of breaking down my wheel?

Comment: How large? There's a big difference between a 5 lb wheel and a 25 lb wheel.

Answer (score 10):

Soft cheeses are best sliced using wire, which is easy to work with and avoids squishing the cheese. Hard cheeses, like Parmesan, are difficult to cut with a wire. These cheeses are often (as you say) scored and then split with a prying action. If the cheese is sufficiently dry, it will easily break apart in sections. You can do this with an ordinary knife, or use a specialized cheese knife such as [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004S1DC).

Gouda is kind of in a middle ground, being a semi-hard cheese. Some specimens may be too soft to pry apart, and others may be too hard to easily cut with a wire. That said, I would probably try the wire first (the prying apart method usually only works with very hard cheeses). The age of your cheese will give you a rough indication of how hard it is-- Gouda is usually aged [anywhere from 1 month to 3 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouda_cheese).

Answer (score 5):

Use a cheese wire - simplest tool for the job, IME, IMHO. It's just a thin wire with handles. Wrap it around the cheese and pull.

Answer (score -1):

Go online and take a look a cheese monger’s parm set if you’re serious about breaking down large wheels. They have a bunch of cheaper knives as well.